# FB Graph API comments/?ids=http://example.com not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Currently https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://example.com it's asking for access token, instead showing the result.

Even after I provided the access token, its simply saying "Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type (URL)"

But I remembered, this api was working till last month. I think, this was happened because of FB removed all the v2.0 apis.

I need to fetch the comment_id from the graph api by passing the url, can anyone help me.